# C++: C2280 Error: Can't set matrix entry to a given value

Tags: c++

I created a vector matrix with my own `Environment` type and I want to give it a specific `Environment` value at a given position, but then the C2280 error occurs. (C2280 "Environment &Environment::operator =(const Environment &)" : Attempting to reference a deleted function)

The `Environment` class takes 3 arguments: a `x` and `y` position in the matrix and a `char envChar`. Here it's `i`, `y` and `lineChar`.

that's the `Environment`header

```
class Environment {
private:
    const int x, y;
    EnvironmentType eType;

public:
    Environment(int x, int y, char envChar);

    char getChar() const;

    static EnvironmentType getEType(char letter);
};
```

that's the `Environment` constructor:

```
Environment::Environment(int x, int y, char envChar)
    :
    x(x),
    y(y),
    eType(getEType(envChar))
{}
```

`EnvironmentType` is just a enum class:

```
enum EnvironmentType {
    FLOOR, ROBOT_START, PATCHBOT_START,
    SERCRETPASSAGE, CONCRETEWALL, STONEWALL,
    MANUAL_DOOR, AUTOMATIC_DOOR,
    ALIENGRAS, GRAVEL,
    ABYSS, WATER,
    SERVER, GRAVE
}
```

that's the line throwing the error:

```
mapObjMatrix[i][j] = Environment(i, j, lineChar);
```

the `i` and `j` come from a nested for-loop. `mapObjMatrix` has type `std::vector<std::vector<Environment>>`.

that's a snippet from the constructor (not from the  `Environment` class):

```
objMatrix mapObjMatrix(mapHeight, std::vector<Environment> (mapWidth));
this->mapObjMatrix = mapObjMatrix;
```

If more code is needed to specify the problem, just ask. I don't know if this will suffice.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @rafix07 That's my `Environment` constructor: 
`
Environment::Environment(int x, int y, char envChar)
 :
 x(x),
 y(y),
 eType(getEType(envChar))
{}
`
The last part `eType(getEType(envChar))` turns the given envChar to an enum value

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] containing the full error message.

Comment: C2280 "Environment &Environment::operator =(const Environment &)" : Attempting to reference a deleted function

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and add the error message to your question. A [mcve] can be copied and pasted and reproduces your problem. It's also minimal. Remove every line of code that is not necessary.

Comment: I'm reallly sorry, that it takes so long for me to provide all the code needed to specify the problem

Comment: This `std::vector<Environment> (mapWidth)` cannot work, because you defined custom constructor so default ctor is not generated by compiler. `std::vector<Environment> (mapWidth)` - it tries to create `mapWidth` instances of `Environment` by calling default ctor.

Comment: @rafix07 While that is true, it is not explaining the error message that OP is asking about.

Comment: @rafix07 `objMatrix` is a typdef for `vector<vector<Environment>>` so it is a vector matrix. How do I set the height and width of that matrix correctly?

Comment: @uneven_mark `mapObjectMatrix` is  a `vector<vector<Environment>>`

Comment: my mistake, issue is obvious, your class has **const** data members which can be initialized only in CTOR. You cannot reassign them in copy assignment operator. Remove *const* from this line `const int x, y;` and try compile again.

Comment: @rafix07 but why does it work here then `lineMatrix mapLineMatrix = lineMatrix(mapHeight);
 this->mapLineMatrix = mapLineMatrix;` 
`lineMatrix` is a vector<string>

Comment: This `lineMatrix mapLineMatrix = lineMatrix(mapHeight);` looks like assignment, but here is called constructor not copy assignment operator, so in ctor **const** member variables can be set. It is the same as `lineMatrix mapLineMatrix(mapHeight);`

Comment: Please don't fix mistakes that are relevant to the original question in the question itself. You are also not supposed to tag your IDE if the problem isn't specific to it. I have reverted your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @rafix07 explained already in the comments, you have two problems.

First, the error message you are mentioning states that the copy assignment operator of `Environment` is not available.

This means that `mapObjMatrix[i][j] = Environment(i, j, lineChar);`, which is assigning an `Environment` to another `Environment` has no matching operator overload to do this assignment.

The reason that the copy assignment operator is not available (as it usually is by default), is that you are using `const` members in `Environment`. `const` variables can not be changed after initialization, so assignment to them is impossible. Remove the `const` in front of `const int x, y;` and that error will vanish.

Then second, you are trying to use `std::vector<Environment> (mapWidth)` which requires a default constructor in order to construct the `Environment` elements in the vector. You have not defined a default constructor and there is also no implicitly declared one (because the implicit default constructor is not declared when you have any user-provided constructors as you do) and so this will also generate an error message.

You can fix this by defining a default-constructor:

```
Environment();
```

for your class `Environment`.

Comment: removing `const` from `int x, y` worked out exactly as predicted and led to the second problem, which you also immediately solved. Big big thanks :)

Comment: but I've got one more question: it seems, that I can't make `int x, y` `const`, but it'd be favorable, if I could, because `x` and `y` are positions of a tile on a map, so it'd be nice if the position were inchangable

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy If you want them to be unchangeable, then what do you expect `mapObjMatrix[i][j] = Environment(i, j, lineChar);` to do? The left-hand side already contains an `Environment` with its `x` and `y`. They cannot be changed. If your intention is to just create the vector without first default-constructing the elements and then assignment new ones, then you should not use `std::vector<Environment> (mapWidth)`, but `std::vector<Environment>()` and then `push_back` instead of `mapObjMatrix[...] = `. In that case no assignment or default construction is done and you can leave your class as is

Comment: If I have  `vector<int> vec` and do `vec[1] = 5` it works and I intended to have an empty `mapObjMatrix` and then fill it entry by entry with the `Environment` objects

Comment: I was told by my tutor that using `push_back` is not a good way to do so, because it's very memory inefficient and that i should create an empty matrix, because i have height and width, and fill it

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy Yes if works with `vector<int> vec`, but not with e.g. `vector<const int> vec` for the same reason. If you just want to fill up the vector with new elements use `objMatrix mapObjMatrix(mapHeight);` and `mapObjMatrix[i].push_back(Environment(i, j, lineChar))` or `mapObjMatrix[i].emplace_back(i, j, lineChar);`.

Comment: @Cpt.Crazy While it may be true, that is bad advice to a beginner. Does the speed of execution really matter that much for your program? If it really is bad, then you can call `mapObjMatrix[i].reserve(mapWidth);` for each `i` once. It will reserve the necessary space for all elements, but will not actually create them until you do `push_back`. This should remove any real performance penalty. In contrast `std::vector<Environment> (mapWidth)` reserves the necessary space and already constructs all the elements (with the default constructor which the code in your question lacks).

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'll try to go with not making `int x, y` `const` variables for now, because once they're set, they shouldn't be changed later on, as far as I know. But if that's not the case I already have a solution thanks to you ;)